# Create view with calculation of using aggregrate function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have below table `IS_ID`:

```
CREATE TABLE  
    IS_ID  
    (  
        IDENTIFIER VARCHAR2(50),  
        ALLOCATIONPERCENTAGE NUMBER(19,8),  
        MARKETVALUEHELD NUMBER(19,8),  
        ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE VARCHAR2(100)  
    );
```

I want to create a View based on this table with some calculation. For each identifier there will be two rows, one for `ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE = 'Cash'` and second for `ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE = 'Other'`

In first Row where `ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE = 'Cash'`:

For example for each same IDENTIFIER  i wanted to sum the `ALLOCATIONPERCENTAGE` where `ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE = 'Cash'`.

For each same Identifier i wanted to sum `MARKETVALUEHELD` where `ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE = 'Cash'`.

In second row where `ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE = 'Other'`:

For example I want to do below calculation:

100 - sum of all `ALLOCATIONPERCENTAGE` where `ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE ! = 'Cash'` - sum the `ALLOCATIONPERCENTAGE` where `ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE = 'Cash'`

Sum of all `MARKETVALUEHELD` for each same Identifier - Sum of `MARKETVALUEHELD` for each same Identifier where `ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE = 'Cash'` - Sum of `MARKETVALUEHELD` for each same Identifier where `ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE != 'Cash'`

Is it possible to create a view in such case ?

Comment: Use `case when allocationassettype = 'Cash' then 'Cash' else 'Other' end` and Group By it

Comment: Also asked and being discussed at https://community.oracle.com/thread/4343179

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a union of two queries, one which aggregates the cash values, and the other which uses conditional aggregation:

```
select identifier,
  sum(allocationpercentage),
  sum(marketvalueheld),
  'Cash'
from is_id
where allocationassettype = 'Cash'
group by identifier
union all
select identifier,
  100
    - sum(case when allocationassettype != 'Cash' then allocationpercentage else 0 end)
    - sum(case when allocationassettype = 'Cash' then allocationpercentage else 0 end),
  null,
  'Other'
from is_id
group by identifier;
```

```
IDENTIFIER   | SUM(ALLOCATIONPERCENTAGE) | SUM(MARKETVALUEHELD) | 'CASH'
:----------- | ------------------------: | -------------------: | :-----
LU0138075311 |                     .1961 |            242708.64 | Cash  
IE0031069382 |                     .4451 |            552520.67 | Cash  
LU0138075311 |                   58.8989 |                      | Other 
IE0031069382 |                   56.8158 |                      | Other
```

and you can then turn that into a view:

```
create view your_view (identifier, allocationpercentage, marketvalueheld, allocationassettype)
as
select identifier,
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9ccbc79ca867e15ea6ddee4f20459cd2)

> Is it possible to keep the existing IDENTIFIER as well then for each Identifier we can add two more rows for allocationassettype = 'Cash' and allocationassettype = 'Other'? So i can see existing data as well for each Identifier and also see this two new rows ?

You can add a third branch with the original data, but you may need to change at least the 'Cash' label in the aggregate branch, and/or might need a flag to help identify what is original data and what is aggregated; this does both:

```
select identifier,
  allocationpercentage,
  marketvalueheld,
  allocationassettype,
  1 as data_type
from is_id
union all
select identifier,
  sum(allocationpercentage),
  sum(marketvalueheld),
  'Cash total',
  2 as data_type
from is_id
where allocationassettype = 'Cash'
group by identifier
union all
select identifier,
  100
    - sum(case when allocationassettype != 'Cash' then allocationpercentage else 0 end)
    - sum(case when allocationassettype = 'Cash' then allocationpercentage else 0 end),
  null,
  'Other total',
  3 as data_type
from is_id
group by identifier;
```

and then when that is a view, you can order it to a kind of sensible result:

```
select identifier, allocationpercentage, marketvalueheld, allocationassettype
from your_view
order by identifier, data_type;
```

though this now sounds like something you should be doing in a data presentation layer really, rather than in SQL.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f6a1dd475999ac01bd54b0a42a729cef)

> for the Identifier where allocationassettype != 'Cash' is not present then those two new rows with 'Cash total' and 'Other total' will not appear for those Identifier

'Other total' will already always appear. TO make 'Cash total' also appear just change the first branch of the union to use conditional aggregation as well, and remove its filter:

```
...
UNION ALL
SELECT
    IDENTIFIER,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    SUM(case when allocationassettype = 'Cash' then allocationpercentage else 0 end),
    SUM(case when allocationassettype = 'Cash' then marketvalueheld else 0 end),
    'Cash total'
FROM
    IS_ID
GROUP BY
    IDENTIFIER
UNION ALL
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=88c08add9f586d52bf216e87ef57156f) (look for ID 'ABC' for the relevant changes to the output).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219805/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-poole-create-view-with-calculation-of-using-aggregr).